# Cryptic crossword clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

After some feedback on my last question I'll attempt a few more cryptic clues:

> 1. Roll in attempt to become jury (8)
> 2. A string of three, maybe four of all the letters. (4)
> 3. Proceed! Upset mafia boss surrounds retreating, uncooked food. (6)
> 4. Find praise in adult at ion conference with no tea (9)
> 5. Crazy, unneeded veal, won't rise, missing Ed. (10)

I don't think it's pertinent to any clues here, but just in case, I'm a British English speaker; all clues are written in BrEng.

Comment: These are great... can't get enough of them.

Comment: It seems better to post these individually.  You then get to accept an answer to each one.

Comment: You're coming a long way!  These are much better.  #1 and #5 are excellent.  Hope to see more!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1:

> **tribunal**: bun (roll) inserted into trial (attempt)

2:

> **cord**: c (letter 3) or d (letter 4) of the alphabet

4:

> **adulation**: no tea (t) in adult. (adult-at-ion). praise

Comment: Good start. Did you know you can create "spoiler blocks" by prepending a line with ">!". This will cause other users to have to mouse over to see the text.

Comment: @JamesWebster I do now :)

Answer (score 4):

Got a couple:

Proceed! Upset mafia boss surrounds retreating, uncooked food. (6)

> ONWARD - Proceed, or onward! As one might say; anagram of (upset) DON (mafia boss) around (surrounds) RAW (uncooked food) backwards (retreating)

Crazy, unneeded veal, won't rise, missing Ed. (10)

> UNLEAVENED - As in bread that "won't rise"; anagram of (crazy) UNNEED VEAL (unneeded veal missing the letters of Ed)